# Soundmanager2 won't load sound from google translate

Tags: soundmanager2

I want to speak some text; I can get the audio-file(mp3) from google translate tts if I enter a properly formatted url in the browser.

But if I try to createSound it, I only see a 404-error in firebug.

I use this, but it fails:

```
soundManager.createSound( 
  {id:'testsound', 
   autoLoad:true,
   url:'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=da&q=testing'}
 );
```

I have pre-fetched the fixed voiceprompts with wget, so they are as local mp3-files on the same webserver as the page. But I would like to say a dynamic prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I see this was asked long time ago, but I have come to a similar issue, and I was able to make it work for Chrome and Firefox, but with the Audio Tag.

Here is the demo page I have made

http://jsfiddle.net/royriojas/SE6ET/

here is the code that made the trick for me...

```
var sayIt;

function createSayIt() {

    // Tiny trick to make the request to google actually work!, they deny the request if it comes from a page but somehow it works when the function is inside this iframe!

    //create an iframe without setting the src attribute
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    // don't know if the attribute is required, but it was on the codepen page where this code worked, so I just put this here. Might be not needed.
    iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-pointer-lock');
    // hide the iframe... cause you know, it is ugly letting iframes be visible around...
    iframe.setAttribute('class', 'hidden-iframe')

    // append it to the body
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // obtain a reference to the contentWindow
    var v = iframe.contentWindow;

    // parse the sayIt function in this contentWindow scope
    // Yeah, I know eval is evil, but its evilness fixed this issue...
    v.eval("function sayIt(query, language, cb) { var audio = new Audio(); audio.src = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=' + language + '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(query); cb && audio.addEventListener('ended', cb);  audio.play();}");

    // export it under sayIt variable
    sayIt = v.sayIt;
}
```

I guess that I was able to byPass that restriction. They could potentially fix this hack in the future I don't know. I actually hope they don't...

You can also try to use the Text2Speech HTML5 api, but it is still very young...

IE 11 is not working with this hack, some time in the future I might try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Even though you see this as a 404 error, you're actually running into a cross-domain restriction.

Some of the response headers from that 404 will also give you a clue of what's going on:

```
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

So, you won't be able to do this client-side, as Google does not (and probably will never) allow you to do so.

In order to do this dynamic loading of audio, you need to work around this x-domain restriction by setting up a [proxy on your own server](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy), which would download whatever file requested by the end-user from Google's servers (via wget or whatever) and spitting whatever data comes from google.

Code I used to reproduce the issue:

```
soundManager.setup({
    url: 'swf',
    onready: function() {
        soundManager.createSound({
            id:'testsound', 
            autoLoad:true,
            url:'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=da&q=testing'
        });
    }
});
```

Your code should look like this:

```
soundManager.createSound({
    id:'testsound', 
    autoLoad:true,
    url:'/audioproxy.php?ie=UTF-8&tl=da&q=testing' // Same domain!
});
```

Regards and good luck!